# GLM in visual studio 2015 cmath

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, standard-library, glm-math

When including GLM to project intellisense is giving me the following errors:

*namespace "std" has no member "trunc"

namespace "std" has no member "round"

namespace "std" has no member "isnan"

namespace "std" has no member "isinf"

namespace "std" has no member "log2"*

I've done my research and found that these functions were removed from the standard cmath library.

My question is, how will I get it working again without going into the GLM source myself?

With kind regards,

Jesse

Edit:

I noticed these functions were present in the concurrency::precise_math namespace within the amp_math.h library.
So I changed it in the GLM library. Not sure if this was a good thing, feedback is welcome.

Comment: Where did you get the information that those functions got removed?